# Fatal errors trying to Authorise Quickbooks Online in sandbox mode (Consolibyte PHP framework)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to manually connect with my App on Quickbooks online authorising with Oauthv2.0 using the consolibyte authorisation button located at

```
https://www.example.com/quickbooks-php/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/quickbooks-php/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php
```

I'm getting the following fatal error message in oauth.php when trying to authorise Quickbooks online in Sandbox mode using the consolibyte quickbooks php  framework on my secure domain.

I have made sure I'm using the correct development id / secret and that Oauth 2.0 is turned on and saved in the Intuit developer Settings for my app but can't see what is causing this error.

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in ---quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/Encryption/Aes.php:34 
Stack trace: #0 ---quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/Driver.php
(1433): QuickBooks_Encryption_AES::encrypt('XXXXXXXX', 'a:2:{i:0;s:778:...')

\#1 ---quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php
(489): QuickBooks_Driver->oauthAccessWriteV2('XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX...', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX...', XXXXXXXXXXXX...', '2019-09-12 16:1...', '2019-12-22 15:1...', 'XXXXXXXXXXX') 

\#2 ---quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php
(25): QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere->handle(XXXXX) 

\#3 {main} thrown in ---quickbooks-php/QuickBooks/Encryption/Aes.php on line 34
```

Top part of Config file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Require the library code
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';

//development id and secret
$oauth_client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$oauth_client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens

$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'https://www.example.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

$quickbooks_success_url = 'https://www.example.com/quickbooks-php/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';

$quickbooks_menu_url = 'https://www.example.com/quickbooks-php/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';  

$dsn = 'mysqli://db_username:XXXXXXXXXX@ipaddress/db_name';    

// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = 'xxxxxxxx';  //default value used here 

// Scope required
$scope = 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting ';
```

Comment: Did you perhaps try a Google search for "Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open()"? You're missing a required PHP module...

Comment: Thanks Keith, you are right, my shared hosting will not support the mcypt php module at all. Problem solved, next step an alternative hosting solution.

Comment: An update on this, I have now put this onto a cloud server with mcrypt enabled.  However I'm still getting an identical error as previously, any ideas?

Comment: If you're still getting an error about mcrypt being undefined, then your server _doesn't have mcrypt_.

Comment: Thank you Keith, I have now successfully authorised a connection on my nginx server by downgrading from PHP 7.2 to 7.1 and installing the mcrypt package.